# Django - query (month/day) filter only works when USE_TZ = False

Tags: python, mysql, django

How can I get the "latest_events_list" query below to work with day/month?

The below query only works if USE_TZ = False in settings.py. When I set USE_TZ = True, it doesn't query any objects.

Query for "year" works regardless of USE_TZ settings.

**begin_datetime** is a ***DateTime field*** in Event model.

```
views.py

today = datetime.datetime.now()

# list of events ordered and filter
latest_events_list = Event.objects.filter(begin_datetime__day = today.day)
```

My guess has to do with UTC and localtime - but I'm not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Try with this in your `settings.py` file: `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'` and `USE_TZ = True` also set the `timezone` to your database.

Comment: Worked perfectly - my MySQL database was System TimeZone not UTC. Cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Gocht helped mention in his comment above:

My MySQL server timezone needed to be in UTC time zone.

In addition, for those looking to change server time zone - be sure to restart the server or else changes may not take place.

Cheers