# Filter DateTimeField By Month Without USE_TZ as False

Tags: python, django

I want to filter a datetimefield `pub_date` by year and month. But due to `USE_TZ =True` in settings, Django can't get to filter by month. If I should remove the month from the query and put only year, it will work. And if I should set `USE_TZ` to `False`, the below query will work.

Now, how do I filter by month without setting `USE_TZ` to False?

```
zc = TxHistory.objects.filter(pub_date__year=datetime.today().year, pub_date__month=2)
```

I'm on Django 2.1 and Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

As answered here: [Django - query (month/day) filter only works when USE_TZ = False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444863/django-query-month-day-filter-only-works-when-use-tz-false)

This is most likely because the TIME_ZONE set in your settings.py is different to your server/ database timezone. Make sure they both use the same type (e.g. 'UTC') and try this query again.