# How to query data with datetime month paramenter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have filter function to query data based on month. I use Calendar. Here is my code :

```
def ListAll(request):
    list_month = list(calendar.month_name)[1:]
    list_year = Year.objects.all()
    objects = Rental.objects.filter(is_terminate = True).order_by('-created')
    year_query = request.GET.get("year")  
    month_query = request.GET.get("month")  
    if  month_query :
        month_number = list(calendar.month_name).index(month_query)
        month_number = int(month_number)
        objects = Rental.objects.filter(is_terminate=True, created__month=month_number, created__year=year_query).order_by('-created')
    context = {
        'objects':objects, 'list_month': list_month, 'list_year': list_year
    }
    return render(request, 'report_rental/all.html', context)
```

Here is my model:

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
    active_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_terminate = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    terminate_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

My problem is, i got Empty data with query using month with this `objects = Rental.objects.filter(is_terminate=True, created__month=month_number, created__year=year_query).order_by('-created')`

Does anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your models? And also edit and add more tags.

Comment: I already add model

Answer (score 0):

Try using [array.tolist()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.tolist) to convert the `calendar.month_name` array into a list instead of using the `list()` function.  I don't think the `list()` function will convert the array into the list you expect.  Try `print(calendar.month_name)` to check this.

```py
def ListAll(request):
    list_month = list(calendar.month_name)[1:]
    list_year = Year.objects.all()
    objects = Rental.objects.filter(is_terminate = True).order_by('-created')
    year_query = request.GET.get("year")  
    month_query = request.GET.get("month")  
    if  month_query:
        month_number = calendar.month_name.tolist().index(month_query)
        #month_number = list(calendar.month_name).index(month_query)
        month_number = int(month_number)
        objects = Rental.objects.filter(is_terminate=True, created__month=month_number, created__year=year_query).order_by('-created')
    context = {
        'objects':objects, 'list_month': list_month, 'list_year': list_year
    }
    return render(request, 'report_rental/all.html', context)
```

Comment: Oke, I will try It. But for now i just found my answer. I just disabled USE_TZ = False

Comment: Glad you got it to work, @Mar_TO, but take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones-faq, for issues that may arise, and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444863/django-query-month-day-filter-only-works-when-use-tz-false for a possible workaround since I guess my solution did not work.  Good luck.